# How to allow a user to search for elements

Tags: java

I made a small test class that uses the Set interface to get rid of duplicates in a list. How would I be able to have a user search this list?

Below is the program I have so far:

**Updated I have made a method for the search function, there is an error that breaks the program.

```
/*
 * This program will read a series of first names and eliminate duplicates
 * by storing them in a Set. Allow the user to search for a first name.
 * 
 */
package Exercises;

/**
 * 8/25/2016
 * @author Demond
 */
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Duplicate_Elimination2
{

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] names = {"Demond", "Demond", "Joe", "Rose", "Ashely"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(names);
        System.out.printf("List: %s%n", list);

        printNonDuplicates(list);
        searchNames(names);
    }

    private static void printNonDuplicates(Collection<String> values)
    {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(values);

        System.out.printf("%nNonduplicates are: ");

        for (String value : set)
            System.out.printf("%s ", value);

        System.out.println();
    }

     // search names from list
   private static void searchNames(String[] names)
   {
      // get name from standard input
      System.out.println(
         "Search a name, type end to stop search:");
      String inputName = scanner.next();

      // obtain input until end entered
      while (!inputName.equals("end"))
      {
         // name found
         if (names.contains(inputName))
            System.out.println(inputName + " found in set");
         else  // name not found
            System.out.println(inputName + " not found in set");

         // get next search name
         System.out.println(
            "Search a name, type end to stop search:");
         inputName = scanner.next();
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Define how you think the user will search. Will they type the exact name? The start of the name? Any part of the name?

Comment: @Jason Um, whichever way of searching is easier to implement. I just need the program to allow searching, not too concerned with the how the program will do it right now. If you show one way of doing it I can figure out how to modify it later.

Comment: @Jason the code you provided doesn't work and by simple, I meant using input statement that will allow the user to search the HashSet for the names provided by the array: I have updated my code if anyone could debug the error that would help.

Comment: Can you please include the error that breaks your program?

Comment: Answer edited below. And compiled and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `.contains()` on a `String[]`.

The solution is to pass the list to `searchNames()`:

```
searchNames(list);
```

... and then change the parameter type in your `searchNames` method:

```
private static void searchNames(List<String> names) {
```

Of course, your search is performing an exact match, so if you don't get the spelling and capitalisation exactly correct, the name won't be found.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do. I looked at other people code but they had the user inputting the names I didn't want the user to add names to the list.